# How to get sign date of a digitally signed XML file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, date, digital-signature

I have a few XMLs that were digitally signed I receive from someone else. I want to know **when** they were **signed**. Is there a way to do it in C#? If it's not possible in C#, what is a way to do it? The below is the part where I identified as the signature.

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#ID_1"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>5Ps8e+4Obgw0iBgVGeekUaM0D0qkAc6L1wUtYo6h2xM=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>ITAt3eN+iRmiX9AifjEVCqgt2GQUMz6VlcfdPNTuz6Z01mbNpDH5LSIRlieLXmj6H75jWPVwXZHz
azEkQ9MQdeLknRmxRmtQgruf8EPF9PtfflyBBCvpg6cUEZ3qdTg366HrXiyZAIu20Z0CBd+S2l5H
YN0Px1qLNYHx9Xs/nVA=</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:KeyValue><ds:RSAKeyValue><ds:Modulus>03RS2Pm81cvHe4rSmD42+XdXA+k8QZsgbQcMx6A+mtWhKPrG0WaeScwjJHDwmWDjovy3u7bvUAIe
wjoi78OQArMCQDNOKOcm4rXZDsjKQ3JLCZxGfHhiktazMVWxskvGIemAk3MNyH/ObjnZqxJqnRxc
zceDL4TFimkP6Gr3eR8=</ds:Modulus><ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent></ds:RSAKeyValue></ds:KeyValue><ds:X509Data><ds:X509SubjectName>UID=xxxxxxxxxxxx,CN=xxxxxxxxxxx,C=xx</ds:X509SubjectName><ds:X509Certificate>MIIEdTCCA12gAwIBAgIQVAm82EQIjzMOB0FYGDoBNzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBaMQswCQYDVQQG
EwJWTjE3MDUGA1UECgwuQ8OUTkcgVFkgQ+G7lCBQSOG6pk4gVknhu4ROIFRIw5RORyBORVctVEVM
RUNPTTESMBAGA1UEAxMJTkVXVEVMLUNBMB4XDTE3MDMwMzA4MDE1MVoXDTE4MTEyMjE1Mjc1Mlow
ZDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVk4xNTAzBgNVBAMMLEPDlE5HIFRZIFROSEggR09LSURTIEThu4pDSCBW4buk
IEdJw4FPIEThu6RDMR4wHAYKCZImiZPyLGQBAQwOTVNUOjAzMTQyMjAxOTcwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcN
AQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBANN0Utj5vNXLx3uK0pg+Nvl3VwPpPEGbIG0HDMegPprVoSj6xtFmnknM
IyRw8Jlg46L8t7u271ACHsI6Iu/DkAKzAkAzTijnJuK12Q7IykNySwmcRnx4YpLWszFVsbJLxiHp
gJNzDch/zm452asSap0cXM3Hgy+ExYppD+hq93kfAgMBAAGjggGvMIIBqzBpBggrBgEFBQcBAQRd
MFswLQYIKwYBBQUHMAKGIWh0dHA6Ly9wdWIubmV3Y2Eudm4vbmV3dGVsLWNhLmNydDAqBggrBgEF
BQcwAYYeaHR0cDovL29jc3AubmV3Y2Eudm4vcmVzcG9uZGVyMB0GA1UdDgQWBBT5/Bnew2qKZXB1
D0N16sPDUkcJVDAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFDqL0pU7p7+WCT0XH/fsZHu0VRNP
MFkGA1UdIARSMFAwTgYMKwYBBAGB7QMBCQMBMD4wFwYIKwYBBQUHAgIwCwwJT1NfTmV3XzNZMCMG
CCsGAQUFBwIBFhdodHRwOi8vcHViLm5ld2NhLnZuL3JwYTAyBgNVHR8EKzApMCegJaAjhiFodHRw
Oi8vY3JsLm5ld2NhLnZuL25ld3RlbC1jYS5jcmwwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgTwMDQGA1UdJQQtMCsG
CCsGAQUFBwMCBggrBgEFBQcDBAYKKwYBBAGCNwoDDAYJKoZIhvcvAQEFMBsGA1UdEQQUMBKBEGNh
M2F2bkBnbWFpbC5jb20wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBANEg/qRaajV8zjLmhHPbNOOjfu7paRcw
dJp/guPLbwXmTjgCPRl2OTN5zsSRh76Ofb+oqCVrclsjmUFttMA9gtfZ4WMkrK1Mkf+M4ZC4+URA
d74uOgPDtAgtzPvc7sPVoIdsIhCTBXui5GN51QCr6XD7SI+4yzOnsEKGEJ5r+aml4ZCkiuWoQyQ3
7x7HBhDYd5qblPQKULzv11nertZ6SAUczfSvfXc5cYRcPuBIdH2x7KiRz9FIvofoCkXVVq5i4FV/
FWRs8ZB6M4ZqibXFgW6zn+C583PKniQcUGl1YGEY5l5brYBDeUFN19uCBQF+rrQT5stm5gKUuB35
HZCewXY=</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature>
```

Comment: You would have to add the date to the encrypted portion of the xml.

Comment: @jdweng The XML files are not mine, created by someone else. I do not have control over their creation. I want to check when it was signed. .

Comment: The only way is to check the date of the file which can easily be modified.  Or if the date is inside the decrypted data.  Even then the date may not be correct.

Comment: I have search and found few ways to verify if the signature is valid. So I think there should be inherently a way to get the date of signing. That's how a program can identify if the file is modified after it's signed.

Comment: The date can only be validated if it is part of the signature.